# Error: Conversión no válida desde 'DateTime' hasta 'Int32'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Tengo este problema, ya estuve checando mi código pero no encuentro donde puede estar el problema.

Esto esta ubicado en un modelo:

```
public string Actualizar_Red(string usuario, int idRed, string urlRed)
    {
        string msj = "";
        try
        {
            DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LANDINGPAGE.ACTUALIZAR_REDES", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_ID_RED", idRed);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_FEC_MODI", SqlDbType.Date).Value = fecha.ToShortDateString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_USU_MODI", usuario);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_URL_RED", urlRed);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) != 0)
            {
                msj = "Red modificado correctamente";
            }
            else
            {
                msj = "Ningún cambio realizado";
            }
            con.Close();
            return msj;
        }
        catch
        {

            return "Error de conexión, intente de nuevo";
        }
    }
```

Esto, lo tengo en un controlador:

```
public ActionResult Actualizar_Red(string urlRed, int idRed)
    {

        ViewBag.Message = MD.Actualizar_Red("usuario", idRed, urlRed);
        return Json("");
    }
```

Este es mi procedimiento almacenado:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [LANDINGPAGE].[ACTUALIZAR_REDES]
    @P_ID_RED INTEGER,
    @P_FEC_MODI DATE,
    @P_USU_MODI VARCHAR(200),
    @P_URL_RED VARCHAR(200)
    AS BEGIN SELECT * FROM LANDINGPAGE.REDES
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LANDINGPAGE.REDES WHERE NUMB_ID_RED = @P_ID_RED)
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE LANDINGPAGE.REDES
        SET FECHA_MODIFICACION = @P_FEC_MODI,
            USUARIO_MODIFICACION = @P_USU_MODI,
            URL_RED = @P_URL_RED
    WHERE NUMB_ID_RED = @P_ID_RED
    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as afectadas
    END
END
```

Comment: Hola Fer, has debugeado ? sabes hasta donde el valor es correcto, y donde se pierde, o cual es el lugar donde se produce el error ?

Comment: Hola @FederHico, si ya lo hice, todos los campos los agarra pero en el idRed me lo marca como un cero. Cuando esta situado aquí `if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) != 0)` me manda al `catch` y es cuando me sale el error.

Comment: @Pikoh lo tengo de esa manera porque donde trabajo así me dijeron que dejara ese campo.

Comment: creo que necesitas esto dateDate.Ticks
}

Comment: eso lo utilizan para el formato de la fecha, y lo hace bien.

Comment: La excepción dice se detectó `InvalidCastException` y el error sólo dice eso Conversión no válida desde 'DateTime' hasta 'Int32'.. No me dice número de linea.

Comment: si ya lo probé, pero aún así me sigue saliendo ese error. Tengo otros métodos parecido y si me los hace bien pero en este no se porque no.

Comment: y el valor que trae fecha es un DateTime correcto y válido ?

Comment: Si, es por eso que no se cual puede ser el problema

Comment: estamos todos en el chat chicos.. pueden limpiar esto y seguir alla?? jajaja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomendaria modificar primero tu Stored Procedured y agregarle una variable de salida

```
@afectadas int OUTPUT
```

En tu procedimiento almacenado

```
SELECT @afectadas = @@ROWCOUNT
```

En tu Funcion c# `Actualizar_Red`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LANDINGPAGE.ACTUALIZAR_REDES", con);
SqlParameter afectadas = new SqlParameter("@afectadas", SqlDbType.Int)
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
};
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(afectadas);
//Tu codigo...
conn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_ID_RED", idRed);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_USU_MODI", usuario);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_URL_RED", urlRed);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int numeroAfectadas = int.Parse(afectadas.Value.ToString());
if (numeroAfectadas > 0 )
{
    msj = "Red modificado correctamente";
}
else 
{
    msj = "Ningún cambio realizado";
}
```

De esta manera puedes capturar un valor de salida que ejecuta tu SP.

No se cual es la finalidad de la Fecha, pero si necesitas que siempre sea la actual, podrias dejarle ese trabajo al mismo SP y utilizar `GETDATE()`

```
UPDATE LANDINGPAGE.REDES
    SET FECHA_MODIFICACION = GETDATE(),
```

Comment: donde le pusiste tu codigo es donde ira lo que yo tengo que es lo de el llamado del procedimiento almacenado y sus variables?

Comment: claro, puse solo los cambios que agregue a tu codigo, pero editare y pondre todo

Comment: ah ok ok :D, deja lo pruebo

Comment: cambie el código a esto, pero ahora me dice que `La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto`

Comment: En que linea especificamente?

Comment: cuando me marca el error no me manda linea, pero del `if` se va al `catch`

Comment: @AmairaniFernanda modifique el codigo que agregas la fecha, ahora la fecha la envias tal como la obtienes, sin el String

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59696/discussion-between-amairani-fernanda-and-sioesi).

podríamos hablar por el chat :D

Answer (score 4):

El problema con este código está aqui:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) != 0)
```

`ExecuteScalar` devuelve el valor de la primera columna y la primera fila de los resultados devueltos, lo que en tu caso debe ser un `DateTime`. Si no necesitas recoger datos del procedimiento almacenado, debes usar `ExecuteNonQuery` que devuelve el número de filas afectadas:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()) != 0)
```